# Strange behavior by in-place modifying the list with bools during the for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, in-place

By solving a python exercise, I came across a strange behavior of for-loop that I do not understand.

`move_zeros(array)` should move all zeros of the array to its end.

```
def move_zeros(array):
        for x in array:
                if  x == 0 and x is not False:
                        array.remove(x)
                        array.append(x)

        return array
```

It works just fine for arrays with all kind of item but if the array contains False the result is wrong:

`move_zeros([1,2,0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1]) => [ 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]` (correct!)

but

`move_zeros([0, 1, False, False]) => [1, False, 0, 0]` (incorrect!)

Comment: but it works for the first `False`

Comment: when looping through the copy of the array, it works like expected: `for x in array.copy():`

Answer (score 0):

```
def move_zeros(array):
    new_arr = []
    nulls = []
    for x in array:
      if x:
        new_arr.append(x)
      else:
        nulls.append(x)
    return new_arr + nulls
```

Please, don't change object, through what you iterate...